# Damaged Bosch battery charger IC identification help

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, charger

I accidentally damaged my Bosch cordless drill battery charger by hooking the charger's PCB's 12 volt lines directly to the 220V|50Hz AC mains.

The charger's model is **AL 1110 CV** https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bosch-POWER4ALL-Li-ion-Battery-Charger/dp/B0777RXTKJ

I suspect, that this IC is at fault:

[image: Unknown IC type]

I cannot find much info about it online.

Any help finding this IC (and what it does) or an equivalent alternative will be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You are probably wasting your time - buy a new one.

Comment: It is rated 240V at the plug, why would you even consider that for bypassing to 12V.    Toasted and no char heat marks? Nicely fused open.what about the blown Caps? If U don’t show more details this above you debug pay rate?

Comment: I was mass changing some power tool plugs from UK to EU (Shuko) type, and accidentally, in a hurry, did not notice that this chargers transformer is inside the plug itself :) I see no other (visible) damage on the PCB, so my assumption is that this IC went bad. If it costs < 1-2 USD, why not give replacing it a try? 
Of course I'll buy a replacement charger if I don't think the time and money spent is worth :) It'll be much more helpful if someone can answer the original question - what kind of IC is this?

Comment: Its highly likely that it's a custom IC made for Bosch. Lack of an identifiable part number in high volume equipment usually means they do not want you to be able to repair it. You may be lucky, but, probably not.

Comment: Well, this looks very similar, but still no specs :(
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000373583761.html

Comment: That was a nice find. ST IC. MAY be somewhere in [here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/promotional_material/brochure/group0/a0/df/a5/99/26/e9/43/3d/power-management-guide/files/power-management-guide.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.power-management-guide.pdf) but I couldn't see anything too likely.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you @RussellMcMahon!